# Access a list within an element of a Pandas DataFrame and sum the list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in a dataframe:

```
columnA
[1.,2.3,3.]
[2]
[3,4.]
```

Similiar to other posts in this forum I want to summarize this types of list in my dataframe, so in this case I want to sum the list ups, that I have the new column:

```
columnA
6.3
2
7
```

I tried: 
`df['columnA'] = df5['columnA'].apply(lambda x: x.sum())`which gives the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'`

And i tried: `df['columnA'] = (df['columnA'].values.tolist()).sum(1)`, which gives the same error.

Comment: `df5['columnA].apply(lambda x: sum(x))`?

Comment: gives the error: `'float' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you also have floats in the column. use `isinstance` to check if object is iterable and then use sum

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[[1.,2.3,3.], [2], [3,4.], 10.9]})
df["columnA"] = df["columnA"].apply(lambda x: sum(x) if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) else x)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   columnA
0      6.3
1      2.0
2      7.0
3     10.9
```

Comment: got it, I think It was an error because I have some NaN values in my original dataframe

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
   columnA
0      6.3
1      2.0
2      7.0
3     10.9
>>>
```

Comment: what is the difference to apply?

Comment: @PV8 `applymap` is for each value in the dataframe, and `apply` is for each column.

Comment: so applymap would run it for the full dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[[2.3,2.0,1.2]],[[1.9,1]],[[4.2,0.2,6.8,9.4]]],columns=['ColA'])
data['TotalColA'] = data['ColA'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
                   ColA  TotalColA
0       [2.3, 2.0, 1.2]        5.5
1              [1.9, 1]        2.9
2  [4.2, 0.2, 6.8, 9.4]       20.6
```

Hope, this may solve your problem.

Comment: as you can see form the comments, this is not working, as I have Nan values in it..

Comment: you can replace your NaN values with Zero and then try this, hope this time it works for you as well